# Force WKWebView to show desktop version

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I have a `NSViewController` which displays various `WKWebView` at specific locations inside a NSView. If the frame of the `WKWebView` gets small - it switches to the mobile version of the website. Is there a way to always show the full (desktop version) website in the `WKWebView`?

My first idea was to inject some javascript and set the viewport to a specific size to force the website to display a "Desktop" view.

```
let viewportScriptString = "var meta=document.createElement('meta');meta.name=\"viewport\";meta.content=\"width=1920\";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"

let viewportScript = WKUserScript(source: viewportScriptString, injectionTime: .AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

let controller = WKUserContentController()
controller.addUserScript(viewportScript)

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = controller

let nativeWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)
```

Unfortunately this does not work and the website is still scaled. To demonstrate the behaviour i try to achieve please see the following screenshot.

[image: test]

==EDIT==

thanks for pointing me to some similar questions. I tried the following the solutions that worked for other users. Unfortunately I had no luck. Maybe `WKWebView` is different on macOS - the other questions are about iOS.

- `NSUserDefaults`
- setting the `CustomUserAgent` on `WKWebView`
- setting `ApplicationNameForUserAgent` on `WKWebViewConfiguration`
- adding a `User-Agent` to `NSUrlRequest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request desktop site WKWebview not working in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591964/request-desktop-site-wkwebview-not-working-in-swift-4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load desktop version WKWebView iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434153/load-desktop-version-wkwebview-ios-9)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - I updated my question since non of the solutions from the other threads worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You should change the user agent, for example:

`UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : "Chrome Safari"])`

Comment: thanks for the answer - unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Scaling of the WKWebView is still wrong for me.