# WKWebView run website desktop version - Swift

Tags: swift

I have a html website, as you can see in the photo, double click feature works on the site. But I cannot double click on webview. These features work in Android webview, but not in iOS webview. Can I open the site as if I am opening the computer with WebView? So I want to open it as a desktop version, not mobile.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var davetiyeIlk: WKWebView!

  @objc func webViewCalıstır(){
         let  davetiyeIDCEK = keychain.get("davetiyeeID")
        let stringDavID : String = davetiyeIDCEK!
        let getKullanıcı = keychain.get("kullanıcıID")
        let stringKulID : String = getKullanıcı!
print("stringDavID", stringDavID)
        let url = URL (string: "http://.../Editor/?davetiyeId=\(stringDavID)&kullaniciId=\(stringKulID)")
        davetiyeIlk.load(URLRequest(url: url!))

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5sHk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do that, try adding user agent You can use following code

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent" : "Chrome Safari"])
```

or

```
  self.webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17"
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495706/696134